# what is the necessity of the jsp API?

Tags: java

I am learning java servlet and jsp and wondering the necessity of the JSP API. At the end of the day, all the .jsp scripts we write will be a servlet, so why don't they can be normal servlet which extends the javax.servlet.Servlet interface? What is the use of the javax.servlet.jsp API?

Comment: .jsp page are in the customer side they are not in Java (server side). The display in the browser must be an interpreted language.

Comment: @FoxCy no, .jsp files are created on the server side and will be compiled into servlets. They're basically an easier way to create Servlets because you can use HTML markup etc. directly without having to use all those writer operations that are needed in the servlet.

Comment: @Thomas The JSPs appear on the client side and make the links between Java by running a visual interface at the same time. I never said they were created on the client side but they need to integrate a language that the browser understands for display. My bad, If I have misunderstood it.

Comment: @FoxCy what's sent to the browser is mostly HTML which is generated by a servlet. In the case of JSPs the servlets are automatically generated by the web server but it's still being generated on the server (note that you could render HTML using JavaScript as well but in that case using JSPs wouldn't make that much sense anymore) - what's being sent to the client is HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc. but _not_ JSP (or JavaFX, GWT etc.) code.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's easier to write a template JSP with scriptlets that to write a servlet and all the write or print operations neaded to do the same thing.

Comment: A comment would have worked perfectly

Comment: @bub well that's my answer

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's the choice between writing HTML in Java code (via string/writer operations) or Java code in HTML (aka scriptlets). Of course in the end it will be html in Java code (servlets) but JSPs are meant to make it easier for the developer.

What you would you rather write:

A JSP like this (simplified):

```
...
<html>
  <body style="some style">
    Hello <b><%=user%></b>, how are you?
  </body>
</html>
...
```

Or a servlet like this (the JSP compiler would create something like this out of the JSP file):

```
...
out.write( "<html><body style=\"some style\">");
out.write( "Hello <b>");
out.write( user );
out.write( "</b>, how are you?" );
out.write( "</body></html>");
...
```

The above example doesn't look that complex but imagine you're adding more html and scriptlets in between.

Comment: i know the use of the jsp scripts. they are easier for non programmers to write and they also separate the presentation layer, which is a good thing. but my question is, when the jsp engine translates the .jsp file to a Servlet it uses the the javax.servlet.jsp API, why don't it use the normal Servlet API???

Comment: @seidnuredin `javax.servlet.jsp` contains classes that are used to generate the servlets that represent the JSP and thus are part of the JSP engine. The end result is a servlet class that extends `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` (aka the normal Servlet API).

Comment: the end result doesn't extend the HttpServlet it  extends the HttpJspBase which is part of the javax.servlet.jsp API

Comment: @seidnuredin have a look at `HttpJspBase` which _does_ extend `HttpServlet`.

Comment: public abstract class HttpJspBase extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
implements javax.servlet.jsp.HttpJspPage. so my question is why does it implement the HttpJspPage????

Comment: @seidnuredin well why shouldn't it? `HttpJspPage` is part of the JSP engine API and provides some additional methods needed for the JSP lifecycle. `HttpJspBase` (which basically is just _one_ JSP implementation albeit probably the most widely used) then extends `HttpServlet` to get the basic implementations _and_ implements `HttpJspPage` to hook into the JSP engine.

Comment: ok :) now it starts making sense. so what you are saying is, there is a difference between the servlet that is generated by the jsp engine and any other servlet? ?? what i thought was servlet is servlet it will be excuted by the servlet engine and the work of the jsp engine is only translating jsp codes in to servlet codes.

Comment: @seidnuredin of course there are differences. JSP servlets are servlets but not every servlet is a JSP servlet (JavaFX uses servlets as well for example).

Comment: ok now i get it, thank you very much!!!

Comment: sorry for embarrassing you but here is another thought. why the servlet generated by .jsp file differ from the normal Servlet can you point out some things that makes the jsp servlet differ from the normal Servlet? ?

Comment: @seidnuredin that might be a bit too much for SO so please refer to the documentation on Servlets and JSPs in general. Servlets are just the basic way to serve requests (note there's HttpServlet to serve http requests, i.e. there may be other servlets as well) while JSPs are a specialization of HttpServlets that creates html responses and provides a lot of features to make a developer's life easier.